# Can't access my options page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

The page is listed in the Settings list, but I just get "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

I can access all the other pages listed for "manage_options", so I'm confused.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_init');
function my_admin_init() {
  add_options_page( 'Bork', 'Bork', 'manage_options', 'bork', 'my_bork_page');
}
function my_bork_page() {
  return 'hi';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action should be 'admin_menu' instead of 'admin_init'.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_init');
```